# Flask error "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects" when POSTing multipart form data

Tags: python, forms, http, post, flask

So I'm using flask to receive form data, which has worked fine with url-encoded data (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). I can just access the `request.form` in my routing functions.

However if I try to instead send data using `multipart/form-data`, I consistently get the error: `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects`

This error occurs as soon as I try to access the request form, e.g. the line:
`f = request.form`. So it's nothing to do how I'm actually using the form data. It also happens regardless if I send the data from Fiddler, Postman or my own custom Java app.

Am I missing some code in flask to handle multipart form data, or is the request somehow invalid? Here's an example request from postman that causes the error:
[image]

And here's the full traceback (Locus is my app, so only line 18/19 are from my own code):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_debugtoolbar\__init__.py", line 125, in dispatch_request
    return view_func(**req.view_args)
  File "D:\Programming\VS\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Locus Backend\Locus Backend\locus\Routing.py", line 67, in url_api_create
    f = request.form
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\utils.py", line 71, in __get__
    value = self.func(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 483, in form
    self._load_form_data()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\wrappers.py", line 165, in _load_form_data
    RequestBase._load_form_data(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 355, in _load_form_data
    mimetype, content_length, options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\formparser.py", line 193, in parse
    content_length, options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\formparser.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(self, stream, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\formparser.py", line 208, in _parse_multipart
    form, files = parser.parse(stream, boundary, content_length)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\formparser.py", line 518, in parse
    return self.cls(form), self.cls(files)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures.py", line 371, in __init__
    for key, value in mapping or ():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\formparser.py", line 516, in <genexpr>
    form = (p[1] for p in formstream if p[0] == 'form')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\formparser.py", line 475, in parse_parts
    for ellt, ell in self.parse_lines(file, boundary, content_length):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\formparser.py", line 382, in parse_lines
    next_part = b'--' + boundary
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Comment: What is the full traceback?

Comment: Okay I've added the full trace. Something's definitely happening in formparser.py but I don't see why it couldn't handle a multipart POST

Comment: I note that the boundary set in the Content Type header and the boundaries used in the POST body don't match.

Comment: Yeah I did notice that, but I get the same error even if no is send content (so no boundaries), like this: http://i.imgur.com/1ET870b.png

Comment: A [recent commit to Werkzeug](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/commit/4ae4476e0452aa992d7eecd969cb6a835f9a9aff) guards against this specific error, but you still need to fix your POST Content Type header here.

Comment: I don't actually have control over the boundaries here because I'm using Postman, but it's worked with everything else before. Can I get this Werkzeug commit from pip?

Comment: Yes, `pip` can install directly from GitHub:   `$ pip install git+git://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug.git#egg=werkzeug`